# Windows 7 Pro computer not visible on other Windows 7 Pro "network."

Tags: windows-7, dvd, file-sharing

The laptop has my only DVD player, so we want to mount it (to use Unix terms I'm familiar with) on the desktop.

Both are connected to the same hub and both can read the NAS connected to the hub, and have it mapped to a drive letter.  That all works.

On both computers, I've gone to Control Panel->Network and Sharing Center->advanced sharing settings and have everything on most lenient for Home/Work.  In fact I've even done so for Public, though on the Network and Sharing Center, the "View your active networks" area shows "Home network."

On server (laptop), right click on DVD (E: drive) -> Sharing.  I see Shared and, Network Path: \LAPTOP\dvd .  If I go to advanced sharing, I see that everyone is approved for all operations.

On both computers, if I go to Control Panel->Network and Sharing Center->See full map, I see *both* itself *and* the other computer.

However, on the client computer, Taking Windows Explorer to "\LAPTOP\dvd" (the export name) I see: "Windows cannot access \laptop\dvd  Check the spelling of the name.  Otherwise, there might be a problem with your network.  To try to indeify and resolve network problems, click Diagnose."

Windows Diagnostics on the client says: "Make sure that the device or resource (LAPTOP) allows incoming connections for File and Printer Sharing."

I've turned off both firewalls and rebooted.  Status doesn't change.

Only idea I have is whether I need to open a port on the router?

Comment: Are both computers in the same IP subnet, or are there any routers in between them?

Comment: Did you try putting your laptop's IP address in the address bar? (Something like \\A.B.C.D\dvd\ where A.B.C.D is the IP address usually assigned by your router). Also, what happens if you put only \\LAPTOP\ in the address bar? Do you see other shared folders and resources apart from the _dvd_ folder? Is the laptop visible in the _Network_ section of Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to turn off your firewall. In the both computers, go to Network and Sharing center and view your network location. Then open Windows Firewall with Advanced security and go to inbound rules. Scroll down to File and Printer sharing SMB-in. Click the network profile (Public,Private or Domain) and then allow it. Now go to the scope tab, and in the remote IP address box and enter two subnets by /24  suffixed not at the same line. I.E. 192.168.77.0/24 then you will be able to access resources at other subnet server. And if you are in same subnet, turn network discovery on and check if TCP/IP netbios helper service is running and try to provide the computer's IP address.

Comment: will try tomorrow and report back, thx!